# Unable to connect online with PS3 &PS4

Tags: ps3, ps4

I have my PS4 connected online in the living room but now I want my PS3 online in the bedroom. When the PS3 tries to connect online I get a message of, “ Cannot connect online using someone else’s ID (email) I’m using the same email address and same password on both consoles on the same network. Why can’t I have both consoles connected online using my same account?